# If statement looks acceptable, but has error: expected expression before ‘)’ token

Tags: c, string, gcc, strcmp

I have minimized my code to just what is necessary to reproduce this error. I have what I believe is a perfectly fine if statement, but gcc insists that it is not a valid statement.

```
#define SOMECHAR *

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char* my_string = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char[5]));
    strcpy(my_string, "aa*a");
    int i;

    for (i=0; i< sizeof(my_string); i++){
        if(strcmp(&my_string[i], SOMECHAR) == 0){
            printf("%s", "b");
        } else {
            printf("%s", &my_string[i]);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(my_string)` is size of a pointer

Comment: `#define SOMECHAR *` should be `#define SOMECHAR '*'`

Comment: `#define SOMECHAR *` should be `#define SOMECHAR "*"` anyway, the comparison logic should be `my_string[i] == '*'`

Comment: you leak the memory you just allocated

Comment: Ahhhhhh yes thank you both for pointing those two things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your comments and suggestions, I figured out what I really wanted.
The first problem is to #define a character, it needs to be in single quotes. And sizeof() is totally for describing the size of a pointer, not how long it is. I should be using strlen(). Rookie mistake. And my main method here doesn't have a return, so that would be a problem once fixing the error I already had.

But there's a much better way to do what I needed without looping and condition checking. In string.h there is a function called strchr that will return a pointer to the last character in a string before matching a given character. I've modified my code like this:

```
#define SOMECHAR '*'

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char* line = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char[5]));
    strcpy(line, "aa*a");
    int i;
    char* ending;

    printf("%s\n", line);
    ending = strchr(line, SOMECHAR);
    ending[0] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", line);

    return 0;
}
```

This terminates a given string at the character before the match. Which is what my assignment requires. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, `size_of(my_string)` is size of a pointer, not size of array it point to.

Next, `strcmp(&my_string[i], SOMECHAR)` will be expanded to `strcmp(&my_string[i], *)`, you need to:

```
#define SOMECHAR "*"
```

However, I believe you want this instead:

```
    if(my_string[i] == '*'){
        putchar('b');
    } else {
        putchar(my_string[i]);
    }
```

And as M.M said in comment, you leak the memory you allocated

If you really need to define that character, simply do this:

```
#define SOMECHAR '*'

/*some other code */

    if(my_string[i] == SOMECHAR){
        putchar('b');
    } else {
        putchar(my_string[i]);
    }
```

Comment: For the assignment I'm doing, I unfortunately HAVE to use a define for the character. But this does help. You found a few mistakes I didn't realize I had. Thanks!

Comment: @TurtleDynasty Added that MACRO if you need

Comment: This was helpful. Thank you.